# Error in code to generate new ID in c# sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a VB program that l am converting to C#. I am encountering errors in the unique ID code generator. It checks against an sql server database and reads the Id column. If the column is empty it generates a number for it. Afterwards any number generated will be increased by one. I formatted the Id in my own way. Here is the code

```
     private void btnid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string GetCode = "0";
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AddressBook order by Id desc");
        try {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                if( dr.HasRows == true) {
                    while(dr.Read()) {
                    GetCode = (dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")));}

                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if ((GetCode == "0"))
        {
            txtid.Text = "GPSC0000001";
        }
        else if ((GetCode != "0"))
        {
            string TotalCodeWithoutLable = GetCode.Count - 6;
            string OldNum = GetCode.Substring(GetCode.Length - 
           TotalCodeWithoutLable);

            txtid.Text = "GPSC" + StringFormat(OldNum + 1, 
        "0000000").ToString;
        }
        //format number of casefilenumber

    }
```

VS shows the following errors on this lines.This is the error: Error    1   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

```
     string TotalCodeWithoutLable = GetCode.Count - 6;
     string OldNum = GetCode.Substring(GetCode.Length - 
     TotalCodeWithoutLable);
     txtid.Text = "GPSC" + StringFormat(OldNum + 1, "0000000").ToString;
```

Comment: `GetCode` defined as `string` above , how it can be run `GetCode.Count`?

Comment: Apart from your question, you can change `ExecuteReader` to `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Instead of reading everything you could have used `SELECT MAX(ID)+1`. That can result in duplicate entries though if the last row is deleted, or even two calls are made by separate threads/requests/users. Why don't you use an `IDENTITY` constraint? If you want to retrieve a new value before saving a row create and use a `SEQUENCE` in SQL to generate increasing numbers

Comment: I would generally recommend against generating an ID clientside unless that ID was a GUID type field or the IDs can be otherwise partitioned. Otherwise you will get collisions with multiple clients. If you dont want to partition or use a GUID, Either use a sequence to fetch an ID guaranteed to be never offered to another client, or use an identity field and output the ID it used. Max is also a problem if a concurrent transaction has already used that value depending on your transaction settings.

Comment: so much helpful info...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code,

1- if `DataReader` give you one record then why you are using `while`?

2- why you want to minus `GetCode` length with 6, (I think you want minus itself not it's length).

3- instead of using `(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")))` to get col value you can use `dr["ColName"].ToString()`.

4- At the end it is better your code to be :

```
private void btnid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int max = 0;
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Max(Id) from AddressBook");
    try
    {
        int max = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    if ((max == 0))
        txtid.Text = "GPSC0000001";
    else
    {
        int TotalCodeWithoutLable = max.ToString().Length - 6;
        int OldNum = max.ToString().Substring(max.ToString().Length - TotalCodeWithoutLable);
        txtid.Text = "GPSC" + StringFormat(OldNum + 1, "0000000").ToString;
    }
}
```

or by your way:

```
private void btnid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string GetCode = "0";
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AddressBook order by Id desc");
    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        if (dr.Read())
            GetCode = dr["Id"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    if (string.Equals(GetCode, "0"))
        txtid.Text = "GPSC0000001";
    else
    {
        int TotalCodeWithoutLable = GetCode.Length - 6;
        int OldNum = GetCode.Substring(GetCode.Length - TotalCodeWithoutLable);
        txtid.Text = "GPSC" + StringFormat(OldNum + 1, "0000000").ToString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error as you are trying to assign an (function - integer) value to string; `Count` is function of Linq not a property. 1) Change the GetCode.Count to GetCode.Length and change the variables as int, should fix your problem.

Change the code as

```
 intTotalCodeWithoutLable = GetCode.Length- 6;
 int OldNum = GetCode.Substring(GetCode.Length - 
 TotalCodeWithoutLable);
 txtid.Text = "GPSC" + StringFormat(OldNum + 1, "0000000").ToString;
```